# Space-Shooter game - bullet does't move anymore when I hit the object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fiddle

I am lerning to code in javaScript and for that I am coding a space Shooter game. I came until level 2 so far but now I am having a problem which I can't fix by myself because I am not seeing the problem.

In **level 2** I create some ufos which can shoot with a bullet. When the bullet gets shoot once randomly and the bullet hits the space ship the player looses a live. But when the player (so the space ship) hits the ufo it turns into a coin which the space shit can collect.

**My Problem now:**
When the bullet of the ufo has been shot and is on his way down it stops, when the ufo gets shot by the space ship.

Why? Can someone have a look on my code?

```
// Move the UFO Bullet with the UFO until it's fired
if (!ufo.ufoBullet.isFired) {
  ufo.ufoBullet.x = ufo.x;
  ufo.ufoBullet.y = ufo.y;
  ufo.ufoBullet.element.style.transform = `translate(${ufo.ufoBullet.x}px, ${ufo.ufoBullet.y}px)`;
} else {
  // Move the UFO Bullet straight down when it's fired
  ufo.ufoBullet.y += ufo.ufoBullet.dy;
  ufo.ufoBullet.element.style.transform= `translate(${ufo.ufoBullet.x}px, ${ufo.ufoBullet.y}px)`;
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/k1xesqt5/**

The pictures are not in the code so the fiddle is not really working well. But the **mistake must be in the function updateUFO() I guess.**

Already tried not to remove the ufo object after it got hit by the space ships bullets but nothing worked. Even asked ChatGPT haha.

Here a Picture how it looks. The red bullet doesn't move after the ufo got hit.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when your UFO is shot then in line 180 (`ufos.splice(i, 1);`), you remove `ufo` variable from array `ufos`. Your `updateUFO()` function iterates over array `ufos` and then checks for each UFO in the array for various conditions. Also you have referenced UFO bullets by using `ufo.ufoBullet`, meaning that you iterate over array `ufos`, and then for each `ufo` you move its bullet by using `ufo.ufoBullet`. When you remove `ufo` from array `ufos`, then you can't access that `ufo.ufoBullet` anymore.

That's the problem, for the solution, I would recommend that you keep a separate array `ufoBullets` and then iterate over `ufoBullets` separately, also to know which bullet belongs to which UFO you can create reference in opposite direction (Instead of `ufo.ufoBullet = ufoBullet` use `ufoBullet.ufo = ufo`). But if you want minimal change to your code, then you should add new property to `ufo` variable like `ufo.isDestroyed` which you set to `true` when the bullet is destroyed (in line 179) and also add property `ufo.isRemovable` which is set to `false` if bullet is fired and then is set to `true` when UFO bullet is destroyed. Once both `ufo.isDestroyed` and `ufo.isRemovable` than you can remove `ufo` from array `ufos` (`ufos.splice(i, 1);`). Also, when `ufo.isDestroyed` is set to `true` then you need to skip the part of the code for moving `ufo`.

Comment: First: Thank you so much for your hint! I tried in the last view days but if I want to keep my struture it doesn't really work even with the two new variables. And you other advice I don't really know how I should do that. Do you might have a code approach for me?

Comment: I have it! You were right. I just added a "isHitted" var for the ufo and now it works. Thanks!